# Faces not being drawn properly

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

**Update**

It appears as though my normals are working fine, and it's something with how I'm drawing my faces (only half are being drawn), and I can't figure out why -

[image: Vertices, normals are drawn properly]

If you could take a look at my code from before (shown below)

---

*Original post*

I'm currently working on a parser/renderer for .obj file types. I'm running into an issue with displaying the normal vectors:

Without normals:

[image]

With normals:

[image]

For some reason, I cannot figure out why only half of the normal vectors are having an effect, while the other half act as if there isn't a face at all.

Here is my code for loading in the obj file:

```
    void ObjModel::Load(string filename){
    ifstream file(filename.c_str());

    if(!file) return;

    stringstream ss;
    string param, line;
    float nparam, cur;

    vector<vector<float> > coords;
    vector<float> point;

    while(getline(file, line)){ 
        ss.clear();
        ss.str(line);

        ss >> param;

        //vertex
        if(param == "v"){
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                ss >> nparam;
                this->vertices.push_back(nparam);
            }
        }

        //face
        else if(param == "f"){
            coords.clear();
            point.clear();

            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                ss >> nparam;
                nparam--;

                for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                    cur = this->vertices[nparam * 3 + j];

                    this->faces.push_back(cur);
                    point.push_back(cur);
                }

                coords.push_back(point);
            }

            point = this->ComputeNormal(coords[0], coords[1], coords[2]);

            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) this->normals.push_back(point[i]);
        }

        else continue;
    }
}
void ObjModel::Render(){
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &this->faces[0]);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, &this->normals[0]);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, this->faces.size() / 3);

    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
```

And here is the function to calculate the normal vector:

```
vector<float> ObjModel::ComputeNormal(vector<float> v1, vector<float> v2, vector<float> v3){
vector<float> vA, vB, vX;
float mag;

vA.push_back(v1[0] - v2[0]);
vA.push_back(v1[1] - v2[1]);
vA.push_back(v1[2] - v2[2]);

vB.push_back(v1[0] - v3[0]);
vB.push_back(v1[1] - v3[1]);
vB.push_back(v1[2] - v3[2]);

vX.push_back(vA[1] * vB[2] - vA[2] * vB[1]);
vX.push_back(vA[2] * vB[0] - vA[0] * vB[2]);
vX.push_back(vA[0] * vB[1] - vA[1] * vB[0]);

mag = sqrt(vX[0] * vX[0] + vX[1] * vX[1] + vX[2] * vX[2]);

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) vX[i] /= mag;

return vX;}
```

I've checked already to make sure that there are an equal number of normal vectors and faces (which there should be, if I'm right).

Thank you in advance! :)

**Edit** Here is how I am enabling/disabling features of OpenGL:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
GLfloat amb_light[] =  0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0 ;
GLfloat diffuse[] = {0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1};
GLfloat specular[] = {0.7, 0.7, 0.3, 1};
glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, amb_light);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, specular);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glLightModeli(L_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, GL_FALSE);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
```

Comment: Try `glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE)`

Comment: Tried with it enabled and disabled, however the result was the same

Comment: And the depth test? Is it enabled and set to GL_LESS? Do you clear the depth buffer every frame?

Comment: Yes, I enabled the depth function and clear the buffer each time.

Comment: Could you post your whole .obj loading code?

Comment: Update: normals seem to work fine after combing through it more today, I'm not drawing faces properly (or not drawing all of them for some reason)-

Answer (score 1):

Are you using elements?  Obj files start counting at 1 but OpenGL starts counting at 0.  Just subtract 1 from each element and you should get the correct rendering.

Comment: When I detect that I am at a face, I decrement each element location as soon as I read it in

Comment: I highly doubt it's the normal's problem.  Take a close look and you can see that the triangle on the head is laying diagonally, which means that there's something wrong with your vertices parsing.  Have you tried rendering the model without any normals?  Messed up normals generally don't create that kind of effect.

Comment: The first image is without normals, the second with. Sorry, I didn't make that clear in my OP, I've edited it.

Comment: The first image indicates wrong indices too, see the weird thin triangle from arm to head.

Comment: The messed triangles overlap which makes it look like it's "right".  Have you tried importing a simpler object such as a cube?

Comment: Okay, now I can see the issue being with how I draw/interpret the faces, not with the normals. Could you please look over my code briefly and see where I messed that up? I can't figure out where I went wrong. I'm already decrementing the index that I read in from the file.

Comment: Your code seems fine to me.  Try import a cube, or even just 3 triangles and see what happens.

Comment: With a cube, I get the same issues as before with normals, however the drawing is fine.

Answer (score 1):

The orientation of normals matters. It looks like the face orientation of your object is not consistens, so the normals of neighbor faces, with similar planes, point in opposite directions.

If you imported that model from a model file, I suggest you don't calculate the normals in your code – you should not do this anyway, since artists may make manual adjustments to the normals to locally fine tune illumination – but store them in the model file as well. All 3D modellers have a function to flip normals into a common orientation. In Blender e.g. this function is reached with the hotkey `CTRL + N` in edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) this->normals.push_back(point[i]);
```

That only provides one normal for each face. You need one normal for each *vertex*.